# Validation not working on partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, validation, view

I have a root view with two partial views that get loaded into divs based on a button click:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Donation information</legend>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DonationType.DonationTypex) <br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DonationType.DonationTypeID, ViewBag.DonationTypes as      
        SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "selectList" })
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "ContinueDonation", "Donation", htmlAttributes: new { @id = 
        "btnSelect1" })

    </p>

    <div id="donationSection1"></div>

 <br />
 <input id="btnAddPayment1" type="button" value="Add Payment Info" />
 <br /><br />
 <div id="paymentSection1"></div>

 <input type="submit" id="btnSubmitDonation" value="Save" />
 <input type="button" id="btnCancelDonation" value="Cancel" /> 

 </fieldset>
}
```

The partial views that are loaded into the donationSection1 and paymentSection1 divs share the same Model, just contain editors, labels etc for different properties within it... just wondering how I can get it to validate the partial views... if the submit/save button is on the root view...

...jquery that loads div... (controller returns partial view sharing same model):

```
  $("#btnSelect1").click(function () {
        var donationTypeID = $(this).closest('p').find('#selectList').val();
        var id = parseInt(donationTypeID);
        var route = '/Donation/ContinueDonation?dTypeId=' + id;
        $("#donationSection1").load(route, function () {
            $("#donationSection1").show('slow');
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using jquery validator.unobtrusive.parse

```
$("#btnSelect1").click(function () {
        var donationTypeID = $(this).closest('p').find('#selectList').val();
        var id = parseInt(donationTypeID);
        var route = '/Donation/ContinueDonation?dTypeId=' + id;
        $("#donationSection1").load(route, function () {
            $("#donationSection1").show('slow');
        });
          jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#donationSection1')
        return false;
    });
```

here is the link with more explanations

http://itmeze.com/2010/10/08/client-side-validation-after-ajax-partial-view-result-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

Comment: hmm.. doesn't appear to be working.. do my partial views need form tags themselves... or could the problem be this page is generated originally from index controller method and doesn't have any postback method defined (the subviews do... but submit button is on root view)?

Comment: nope if you have the validations next to the editor it does not matter

Comment: is data validating on the main view not partial

Comment: jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form") try this

Comment: here is one more example http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

Comment: thanks a lot, that seems like the way to go.. for time's sake I think I'm just gonna break my page into two pages to make it easier. Thanks.

Comment: the other way I could get around it would be to put a form in the partial views and just do     $('donationSection1').find('form').submit(); from the root view

Comment: this fixed a problem for me earlier on with input and fields after ajax returns partialResult.  But now I have a select field it is not fixing.